# Chaining dialogs in jQuery mobile: second dialog disappears in Android

Tags: android, jquery, facebook, jquery-mobile, jquery-chaining

I am developing a Facebook app with jQuery mobile, where I create a dialog that creates a second dialog (chaining).

The issue is that with Android and Opera, that second dialog is displayed for a second, and disappears.

Is there a way to avoid this behaviour?
Otherwise, how can I destroy the first dialog without destroying the second one?

**CODE:**

```
function function1(item) {        
       showDialog(..., function(){
               ...
               if (appInstalled == true) {                        
                       if(function2(item) == true) { 
                               //call to alert dialog function2
                       }
               } 
       });
}

function function2(item) {
       if (...) {
               showAlertDialog(item.name, messages.MATCH_CONFIRMATION_MSG, item.picture.data.url, '#friendsPage');
               $('#dialog').dialog('close');
               $('#alertDialogTrickLink').click();//this is event for going to dialog 
       } 

}

function showDialog(title, content, img, hrefURL, hrefURLcancel, callbackFunction) {
       $('#dialog-content').html(content);
       $('#dialogHeader').text(title);
       if (img != null) {
               $('#dialog-img').html('<img src="' + img +'" alt="" class="bigImg" />');
       } else {
               $('#dialog-img').html('');
       }
       var a = messages.ACCEPT_BUTTON_TEXT;
       var c = messages.CANCEL_BUTTON_TEXT;
       $('#dialogActions').html(
               '<a href="' + hrefURL + '" data-role="button" data-theme="c" id="confirmDialogAction" data-icon="check" data-iconpos="left">' + a + '</a>' +       
               '<a href="' + hrefURLcancel + '" data-role="button" id="skipDialogAction" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="left">' + c + '</a>'
       );
       $('#confirmDialogAction').click(function(e) {
               e.preventDefault();
               callbackFunction();
       });
       $('#dialog').trigger('create');
}
```

Thanks a mill

Comment: could you provide a small example?

Comment: Hi Taifun. Just edited with the code that doesn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the `setTimeout` approach described here [Note: Chaining of popups not allowed](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/index.html)